# Homotopic maps from $\mathbb{S}^{n} \to \mathbb{S}^{n}$

Tags: algebraic-topology

I'm trying to prove that if two (continuous) maps $f, g : \mathbb{S}^{n} \to  \mathbb{S}^{n}$ are such that $f(x) \neq -g(x)$ for any $x \in  \mathbb{S}^{n}$, then $f$ and $g$ are homotopic. But I can't seem to have achieved any satisfactory results.

Could anyone please give me a short clue as to how to attack this problem?

I, like anyone who loves mathematics, am not asking for the ***complete*** solution. Rather, I am curious which ideas are used in solving the problem.

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Homotopies in $\mathbb{R}^{n+1}$ often look like $tp(x)+(1-t)q(x)$. We want to do this but restrict it to the sphere. What's the problem if $f(x)=-g(x)$?

Comment: If I got it right, in case of the straight-line homotopy that you mentioned, straight lines represent the (unique) shortest paths between any two points in $\mathbb{R}^{n}$. But for the sphere, there is no _unique_ shortest path between antipodal points. But I don't know how to proceed from here.

Comment: This homotopy doesn't guarantee that all points are on the sphere. The norm of the vector isn't preserved. A homotopy would have to have all vectors be of norm 1.

Comment: If we apply the straight-line homotopy to the sphere, there would be no guarantee that points of the sphere stay on the straight lines during the homotopy.

Comment: That's right, so we have to modify it so that all points are on the sphere. How do you turn a vector into a unit vector that points in the same direction?

Comment: Well, I would take $\frac{\mathbf{v}}{\lVert{{\mathbf{v}}\rVert}}$ as a unit vector in the same direction.

Comment: Apply this to solve the problem.

Comment: Thank you so much, Matt S.

Comment: @Behrooz Sure thing.

Comment: The solution (dividing by norm) only works if it is guaranteed this norm does not take value $0$ for some $t$. This answer is incomplete.

Comment: @drhab That's where the hypothesis $f(x)\neq -g(x)$ for all $x$ comes in. The OP asked for a hint, not a complete answer.

Comment: Okay. This is indeed a 'complete hint'.

Comment: $\lVert tf(x) + (1 - t)g(x) \rVert = 0 \Rightarrow t = \frac{-g(x)}{f(x) - g(x)}$. What does this have to say?

Comment: If it equals 0, then $f(x)=-g(x)$ and $t=1/2$. Remember that they are vectors.

Answer (score 1):

Define the homotopy:

$$H(t,x) = \frac{tf(x) + (1-t)g(x)}{||tf(x) + (1-t)g(x)||}$$

Comment: FYI, this is called the "Straight line homotopy"

Comment: @Alan yes, but it does work in this case doesn't ?

Comment: You have a reason to thank @orangeskid. Btw, is it excluded here that $tf(x)+(1-t)g(x)=\vec0$ for some $t$?